# Why is my data type Any when it started as Int?

Tags: scala, types, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading in a file of directed edges (source and target nodes) with weights; the first part seems to work well:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Q2 {

  case class Edge(src: Int, tgt: Int, weight: Int)
  case class Node(node: Int, weight: Int)

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Q2"))
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

    // read the file to dataframe edges as class Edge
    val edges = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020" + args(0)).map(_.split("\t")).map(e => Edge(e(0).toInt, e(1).toInt, e(2).toInt)).toDF()
    edges.registerTempTable("tempEdges")
```

The assignment is to calculate net messages (weights) in - out.  Following on in the same vein as above, I succeeded in building two dataframes with total in and out values for each node, and joining them ..... I also got it to work by making a unionAll from the in and out dataframes (with negative weights for out) and summing them .... so, problem solved, but along the way I had problems which lead me to try create a Node class and mapping the new dataframes to it:

```
val in =  edges.groupBy("tgt").agg(sum("weight")).map(n => Node(n(0).toInt,n(1).toInt)).toDF()
```

Doing so results in this error:

```
/home/cloudera/hw3-vm/q2/src/main/scala/edu/gatech/cse6242/Q2.scala:30: error: value toInt 
is not a member of Any
[INFO]     val in =  fdf.groupBy("tgt").agg(sum("weight")).map(n => Node(n(0).toInt,n(1).toInt)).toDF()
```

with a pointer to `n(0).toInt`

How is it that what began as an Int has become type Any ?  How do I convert it back to an Int, or better yet, prevent it from becoming Any?

Comment: can you add some sample data ?

Comment: It is just a file with tab delimited integer inputs <source> <target> <weight>, e.g
0/t1/t4/n
0/t3/t57/n
1/t6/t24/n
etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever we use `map` or *any other iterating function* on a dataframe, each iterator is treated as *Trait Row***

So when you do

```
val in =  edges.groupBy("tgt").agg(sum("weight")).map(n => Node(n(0).toInt,n(1).toInt)).toDF()
```

`n` is teated as `Row` and when you try to get data by doing `n(0)` or `n(1)`, `apply()` method of *Trait Row* is called which is defined as

> > ```
> >  /**
> >    * Returns the value at position i. If the value is null, null is returned. The following
> >    * is a mapping between Spark SQL types and return types:
> >    *
> >    * {{{
> >    *   BooleanType -> java.lang.Boolean
> >    *   ByteType -> java.lang.Byte
> >    *   ShortType -> java.lang.Short
> >    *   IntegerType -> java.lang.Integer
> >    *   FloatType -> java.lang.Float
> >    *   DoubleType -> java.lang.Double
> >    *   StringType -> String
> >    *   DecimalType -> java.math.BigDecimal
> >    *
> >    *   DateType -> java.sql.Date
> >    *   TimestampType -> java.sql.Timestamp
> >    *
> >    *   BinaryType -> byte array
> >    *   ArrayType -> scala.collection.Seq (use getList for java.util.List)
> >    *   MapType -> scala.collection.Map (use getJavaMap for java.util.Map)
> >    *   StructType -> org.apache.spark.sql.Row
> >    * }}}
> >    */
> >   def apply(i: Int): Any = get(i)
> >
> >  /**
> >    * Returns the value at position i. If the value is null, null is returned. The following
> >    * is a mapping between Spark SQL types and return types:
> >    *
> >    * {{{
> >    *   BooleanType -> java.lang.Boolean
> >    *   ByteType -> java.lang.Byte
> >    *   ShortType -> java.lang.Short
> >    *   IntegerType -> java.lang.Integer
> >    *   FloatType -> java.lang.Float
> >    *   DoubleType -> java.lang.Double
> >    *   StringType -> String
> >    *   DecimalType -> java.math.BigDecimal
> >    *
> >    *   DateType -> java.sql.Date
> >    *   TimestampType -> java.sql.Timestamp
> >    *
> >    *   BinaryType -> byte array
> >    *   ArrayType -> scala.collection.Seq (use getList for java.util.List)
> >    *   MapType -> scala.collection.Map (use getJavaMap for java.util.Map)
> >    *   StructType -> org.apache.spark.sql.Row
> >    * }}}
> >    */
> >   def get(i: Int): Any
> > ```

So its clear on how `Any` is returned and there is no method `toInt()` defined in *Trait Row*

**Instead there is a method `getAs()` in *Trait Row*** which is defined as

> > ```
> >  /**
> >    * Returns the value at position i.
> >    * For primitive types if value is null it returns 'zero value' specific for primitive
> >    * ie. 0 for Int - use isNullAt to ensure that value is not null
> >    *
> >    * @throws ClassCastException when data type does not match.
> >    */
> >   def getAs[T](i: Int): T = get(i).asInstanceOf[T]
> > ```

So you can do as

```
val in =  edges.groupBy("tgt").agg(sum("weight")).map(n => Node(n.getAs[Int](0),n.getAs[Int](1))).toDF()
//in: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [node: int, weight: int]
```

Or you can directly cast the types by using `.asInstanceOf[Int]`

```
val in =  edges.groupBy("tgt").agg(sum("weight")).map(n => Node(n(0).asInstanceOf[Int],n(1).asInstanceOf[Int])).toDF()
//in: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [node: int, weight: int]
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh, but I'm curious, if that's so, how come the toInt() works ok when called in the first occasion 
val edges = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020" + args(0)).map(_.split("\t")).map(e => Edge(e(0).toInt, e(1).toInt, e(2).toInt)).toDF()
?